# C++ Overloaded + operator in a custom string class using linked list

Tags: c++

After a fairly lengthy session with my instructor and not being able to come up with a concrete solution, I figured I'd come back here for help on a homework assignment. We're supposed to translate the string class to our own version that uses a linked list with a few basic functions. Everything seems to work so far except the + operator function (adding two strings together).

```
string operator +(string& s1, string& s2);
```

What's strange is that it appears to return the correct result when tested, only to cause a crash with a debug assertion failure. I cannot tell why this would be, since the definition:

```
string operator +(string& s1, string& s2)
{
    s1 += s2;
    return s1;
}
```

relies on +=, but that operator works with no issue with the test code in main(). Here's the full code:

HEADER FILE

```
#ifndef STRING2_H
#define STRING2_H
#include<iostream>

namespace string2
{
class string
{
private:
    struct stringList
    {
        char character;
        stringList* link;
    };

    stringList* headPtr;

public:
    // CONSTRUCTORS AND DESTRUCTOR
    string() { headPtr = NULL; };
    string(const stringList* sourcePtr);
    ~string();

    // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    char getChar(const size_t position) const;
    size_t length() const;
    char operator [ ] (size_t position) const;

    // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void operator += (const string& addend);
    void operator += (const char addend[]);
    void operator += (char addend);
    void operator =(const string& source);

    // FRIEND FUNCTIONS
    friend bool operator ==(const string& s1, const string& s2);
};

// NONMEMBER FUNCTIONS
string operator +(string& s1, string& s2);
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const string& source);    
}
#endif
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
#include "String2.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace string2
{
string::string(const stringList* sourcePtr)
{
    stringList* indexPtr;

    if (sourcePtr == NULL)
    {
        headPtr = NULL;
        return;
    }

    headPtr = new stringList;
    indexPtr = headPtr;

    indexPtr->character = sourcePtr->character;
    indexPtr->link = sourcePtr->link;
    sourcePtr = sourcePtr->link;

    while (sourcePtr != NULL)
    {
        indexPtr = indexPtr->link;
        indexPtr->character = sourcePtr->character;
        indexPtr->link = sourcePtr->link;
        sourcePtr = sourcePtr->link;
    }
}

string::~string()
{
    stringList *removePtr;;

    while (headPtr != NULL)
    {
        removePtr = headPtr;
        headPtr = headPtr->link;
        delete removePtr;
    }
}

char string::getChar(const size_t position) const
{
    stringList *indexPtr = headPtr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < position - 1; i++)
        indexPtr = indexPtr->link;

    return indexPtr->character;
}

size_t string::length() const
{
    size_t count = 0;
    stringList* indexPtr = headPtr;

    while (indexPtr != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        indexPtr = indexPtr->link;
    }

    return count;
}

char string::operator [ ] (size_t position) const
{
    stringList* indexPtr = headPtr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < position; i++)
        indexPtr = indexPtr->link;

    return indexPtr->character;
}

void string::operator += (const string& addend)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < addend.length(); index++)
        (*this) += addend[index];
}

void string::operator += (const char addend[])
{
    if (addend[0] == NULL)
        return;

    for (int index = 0; index < (sizeof(addend) / sizeof(addend[0])); index++)
        (*this) += addend[index];
}

void string::operator += (char addend)
{
    stringList *indexPtr = headPtr;

    if (headPtr == NULL)
    {
        headPtr = new stringList;
        headPtr->character = addend;
        headPtr->link = NULL;
        return;
    }

    while (indexPtr->link != NULL)
        indexPtr = indexPtr->link;

    indexPtr->link = new stringList;
    indexPtr->link->character = addend;
    indexPtr->link->link = NULL;
}

void string::operator =(const string& source)
{   
    if (headPtr != NULL)
    {
        delete headPtr;
        headPtr = NULL;
    }

    *this += source;
}

bool operator ==(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
        return false;

    if (s1.headPtr == NULL && s2.headPtr == NULL)
        return true;

    for (int index = 0; index < s1.length(); index++)
    {
        if (s1.headPtr->character != s2.headPtr->character)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

string operator +(string& s1, string& s2)
{
    s1 += s2;
    return s1;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const string& source)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < source.length(); index++)
            outs << source.getChar(index + 1);

    return outs;
}
}
```

TEST CODE (final line is where it breaks)

```
#include "String2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace string2;

int main()
{
string test, test2, test3;

std::cout << "Current length: " << test.length() << std::endl;
char add[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
test += 's'; // testing third (lowest) += operator
std::cout << "First char in string: " << test.getChar(1) << std::endl;
test += 'd';
std::cout << "Current length: " << test.length() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Second char in string:  " << test.getChar(2) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Second char in string testing [] operator: " << test[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Current string: " << test << std::endl;
test += add; // testing second (middle) += operator
std::cout << "Current length: " << test.length() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Current string: " << test << std::endl;

test2 += 'z';
test2 += 'y';
test += test2; // testing first (top) += operator
std::cout << "Current string: " << test << std::endl;

test = test2; // testing = operator
std::cout << "\nCurrent string: " << test << std::endl;
std::cout << "Compared to string: " << test2 << std::endl;
if (test == test2) // testing == operator
    std::cout << "\nStrings are equal" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "\nStrings are not equal." << std::endl;

test += 'f';
std::cout << "\nCurrent string: " << test << std::endl;
std::cout << "Compared to string: " << test2 << std::endl;

if (test == test2) // testing == operator
    std::cout << "\nStrings are equal" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "\nStrings are not equal." << std::endl;

std::cout << "\nTwo strings added together: " << test + test2 << std::endl; // testing + operator
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's a strange definition of `operator+`. I'd expected to see `string operator +(const string& s1, const string& s2);` (notice the `const`)

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can catch the crash as it happens, and learn exactly where in your code it happens, and also be able to examine the involved variables and their values.

Comment: your code has several bugs For example `sizeof(addend) / sizeof(addend[0])` will not work, `addend` has already decayed to a pointer. `getChar` and `operator[]` are inconsistent (shouldn't they be equivalent?). `operator =` leaks memory. When you are done, you might want to submit it to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: An explanation to @WorldSEnder's comment about `operator+` being strange: With your implementation, `string tmp=s1; s3 = s1 + s2; assert(tmp == s1);` would lead to an assertion. This is unexpected because `operator+` is not supposed to modify the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is reproducible with this

```
int main()
{
    string test, test2;
    test += 'h';
    std::cout << "\nTwo strings added together: " << test + test2 << std::endl; // testing + operator
}

string operator +(string& s1, string& s2)
{
    s1 += s2;
    return s1;
}
```

In `operator +`, `return s1` returns a shallow copy of `s1`.So now the internal memory is being occupied by `s1` as well as the returned string from `operator+()`. At the end of `main()` `~string()` is triggered for `s1` which frees the internal memory and then for the returned string from `operator+()` as well which tries to delete the already deleted memory causing double free.

You need a deep copy in `operator+()` or better, a rethink in design of `operator+()`.

Comment: Might be worth noting that currently an implicit copy constructor is inserted by the compiler which only does a shallow copy. Writing your own `string(const string&)` copy constructor would work.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Definitely, but again that won't change the point that `operator+()` is modifying it's arguments, which seems a design flaw.

Comment: Thank you, this set me down the right path. I had actually attempted a proper copy constructor in my code, but was passing the struct as a parameter rather than a whole string object. So I rewrote that function accordingly. I also found a problem in my bottom += operator after all where the end of the lists weren't getting set to NULL correctly.